# FreeIpa DatabaseError on Add user

Tags: centos7, freeipa

I have an ipa server running for over a year now.
Recently, when I try to add a new user via https or the terminal it fails with the following error message.

```
 IPA-Fehler 4203: DatabaseError
 Server is unwilling to perform: Managed Entry Plugin rejected add operation (see errors log).
```

In the error logs, I see:

```
 [timestamp] [:warn] [pid 2731] [client xxx] failed to set perms (3140) on file (/var/run/ipa/ccaches/user@xxx)!, referer: xxx
 [timestamp] [:error] [pid 2727] ipa: INFO: [jsonserver_session] user@xxx: group_find(None, posix=True, version=u'2.230', no_members=True): SUCCESS
 [timestamp] [:warn] [pid 2731] [client xxx] failed to set perms (3140) on file (/var/run/ipa/ccaches/user@xxx)!, referer: xxx
 [timestamp] [:error] [pid 2726] ipa: INFO: [jsonserver_session] user@xxx: user_add(u'xxx', givenname=u'xxx', sn=u'xxx', userpassword=u'********', version=u'2.230'): DatabaseError
```

The user is not created but I have to remove the managed group as described here:
https://www.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-users/2016-August/msg00092.html before I can try again.
What is going on? Any help is appreciated.

```
 $ cat /etc/os-release
 NAME="CentOS Linux"
 VERSION="7 (Core)"
 ID="centos"
 ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
 VERSION_ID="7"
 PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
 ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
 CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
 HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
 BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

 CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
 CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

 $ ipa --version
 VERSION: 4.6.4, API_VERSION: 2.230
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve the Problem.
While experimenting with other settings I tried to add the user without a private group and got the error message:

```
 Server is unwilling to perform: Automember Plugin update unexpectedly failed.
```

A quick search showed, that error is happening, when the user is to be added to a group that does not exist, which happened due to an outdated Auto-Membership-Rule.
Correcting that, the user can be added.